# First row in Toolset table has a black background

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web

I have no idea why the first row of the table on this page has a black background. I feel that this may have a simple solution, but I haven't been able to come up with one myself.

http://cotec.co.nz/products/

Comment: `.scheme_default table>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td` has different background & font color which are overriding defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a black background because of this rule in _colors.css:

```
.scheme_default table>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td
```

Which sets `background-color` to `#1e1d22`.

Comment: In general, becoming familiar with the browser's developer tools will help you immediately identify the cause of this. You can right-click an element on the page, select Inspect, and then find the source of a particular CSS setting for that element.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur css file (_colors.css)

```
.scheme_default table>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #2a2d32;
    border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```

This will update the styling of the 1st rows

A better option will be to add custom class to `td` of that table row only inorder to not break the css styling in some other pages.